# I need help fixing the math for my change calculator

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int GetQuarters(int cents)
{
    int remainder = cents / 25;
    int quarters = cents - remainder / 25;
    return quarters;
}

int GetDimes(int cents)
{
    int dimes = cents / 10;
    return dimes;
}

int GetNickels(int cents)
{
    int nickels = cents / 5;
    return nickels;
}

int GetPennies(int cents)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int cents;
    cout << "How much change do you need? " << endl;
    cin >> cents;

    int quarters = 0, nickels = 0, dimes = 0, pennies = 0;

    quarters = GetQuarters(cents);
    cents = quarters * 25;
    nickels = GetNickels(cents);
    nickels = cents / 5;
    dimes = cents / 10;
    dimes = GetDimes(cents);
    pennies = GetPennies(cents);
    pennies = cents;


    cout << "Quarters: " << quarters << endl;
    cout << "Dimes:    " << dimes    << endl;
    cout << "Nickels:  " << nickels  << endl;
    cout << "Pennies:  " << quarters << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Problems include:

-Quarter values are the same as pennies

-Dime values multiply by 2.5 instead of dividing by 10

-Nickel values multiply by 5 instead of dividing by 5

Additional information:

-the code is designed for the values 0-99

Comment: I recommend you learn how to use whatever debugger is included with your development environment. Step through the code, look at the values of variables, and see where things differ from what you expect.  See [ask], [tour], and [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) debugging.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you, but we are not clairvoyant. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54963849/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a homework question, with deliberate and various mistakes
The main function performs the operations in the wrong order, mathematical operators and variables are switched around.

Nonetheless, in the spirit of answering your question, what you want will be in the form of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int GetCoins(int& centsByRef, int denomination)
{
    int coins = centsByRef / denomination;
    centsByRef -= coins * denomination;
    return coins;
}

int main()
{
    int cents;
    cout << "How much change do you need? " << endl;
    cin >> cents;

    cout << "Quarters: " << GetCoins(cents, 25) << endl;
    cout << "Dimes:    " << GetCoins(cents, 10) << endl;
    cout << "Nickels:  " << GetCoins(cents, 5) << endl;
    cout << "Pennies:  " << GetCoins(cents, 1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Where integer division provides the number of each kind of coin fits into the remaining number of cents, and the value of the coins are subtracted from the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of cents as the remaining cents available after each coin type total is computed.  No need for the functions. This block of code is all you need:

```
quarters = cents/25;
cents -=  quarters * 25;
dimes = cents/10;
cents -= dimes * 10;
nickels = cents/5;
cents -= nickels * 5;
pennies = cents;
```